# How to programmatically use Intellij IDEA code formatter?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, formatting, eclipse-jdt

I use Eclipse jdt to format my generated java files as below :

```
public String format(String code)
        throws MalformedTreeException, BadLocationException {
    Map options = new java.util.HashMap();
    options.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_SOURCE, "1.5");
    options.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_COMPLIANCE, "1.5");
    options.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_CODEGEN_TARGET_PLATFORM, "1.5");

    DefaultCodeFormatterOptions cfOptions =
            DefaultCodeFormatterOptions.getDefaultSettings();
    cfOptions.insert_new_line_after_annotation = false;
    cfOptions.comment_insert_new_line_for_parameter = true;

    cfOptions.blank_lines_before_method = 1;
    cfOptions.number_of_empty_lines_to_preserve= 1;

    cfOptions.tab_char = DefaultCodeFormatterOptions.SPACE;

    CodeFormatter cf = new DefaultCodeFormatter(cfOptions, options);

    TextEdit te = cf.format(CodeFormatter.K_UNKNOWN, code, 0,
            code.length(), 0, null);
    IDocument dc = new Document(code);

    te.apply(dc);
    return dc.get();
}
```

But the question is how can I use the Intellij Idea code formatter API programmatically as above? Has Jetbrains introduced any API?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can programmatically format code in IntelliJ.

The key to doing this is:

```
CodeStyleManager styleManager = CodeStyleManager.getInstance(project);
PsiElement psiFile = event.getData(LangDataKeys.PSI_FILE);
styleManager.reformat(psiFile);
```

I have an example plugin that does just this. Check it out [here](https://github.com/pillravi/invoke-intellij-formatter).

Comment: I am trying to format my generated Kotlin files but without any editor. I have tried that but it is not working. Any other way around?